# How do I left margin in navigation view?

Tags: android, drawer, navigationview

[image]

This is sample for navigation drawer when I create navigation drawer.

and this is code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Import" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Slideshow" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Tools" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

I want put left margin Gallery and Slideshow to show like subgroup in navigation view.

How I can do it?

I group of that   but it is same, not occur

I want see them like subgroup.

If you know about this, please help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542482/how-to-implement-the-navigation-drawer-in-android-with-sub-item-menu

Comment: Thank you for your comment but what do you want show in this link?
Could you explain more about that?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a custom navigation drawer lay out rather than using a menu.

Like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="10dp">

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/drawer_item_icon"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/drawer_item_name"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/drawer_item_icon"
      android:paddingRight="10dp"
      android:textSize="21sp"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

you can define your custom layout attributes in here.

for more details please follow this tutorial

[android custom navigation drawer](http://android-kaizen.com/2014/12/14/custom-navigation-drawer/)

Comment: Thanks but I know about How I can change it in menu