# How to add N-level of Expandable menu in NavigationView android?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-navigationview

In my app I want to add N-level of expandable `Menu` in `NavigationView` like Paytm app screenshot is given below. I have tried to add `ExpandableListView` but didn't understand How to add N-level of expandable menu in `NavigationView` using `ExpandableListView`

If someone know this how to do this then please help me.

[image]

I try from this reference link but can't do https://stackoverflow.com/a/31699975/4395114

Answer (score 2):

Use [this](https://github.com/Polidea/tree-view-list-android) link to create N level listview. And refer your URL to implement drawer.

Comment: You can share some code, link can not be found sometimes.

Comment: @PratikButani definitely I'll be. But this library includes so many classes.