# Showing/hiding submenus with OnClick menu

Tags: javascript, android, menu, navigation-drawer

I am pretty new to this, so I dont know how to explain it correctly, but I want to make menu which will,when I click it, open submenus. That menus need to be in navigation drawer(which I have).So, if you know how Steam mobile app looks, I want to make it like it is there. I have tried with setting visibility on submenus, but whenever I click menu, app just crash. Thank you for any help you can give me.
Here is most important code(at least how i think):

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem settingsItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
    settingsItem.setVisible(false);
    register = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_submenu);
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_menu) {
       register.setVisible(!(register.isVisible()));
    } 

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

And here is log:

> 10-17 22:03:39.467 6307-6307/com.example.user.app D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   10-17 22:03:39.467 6307-6307/com.example.user.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.example.user.app, PID: 6307
>                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.view.MenuItem.isVisible()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                  at com.example.user.app.MainActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:132)
>                                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:153)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:810)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:957)
>                                                                                  at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:328)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5233)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21209)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5507)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   10-17 22:03:39.467 6307-6307/com.example.user.app D/AppTracker: App Event: crash
>   10-17 22:03:39.523 6307-6307/com.example.user.app I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 6307 SIG: 9

Comment: Show us what you have done and the log when it crashes.

Comment: @th3pat3l I did, can you help me now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is [ExpandableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Comment: thanks for reply, I am trying to make it with second answer on this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31446720/how-to-open-sub-menu-after-click-on-menu-item-in-navigation-drawer but i cant figure out what is ExpandedMenuModel. Do you know maybe?